# Method that is present being shown as undefined golang

Tags: go

I am trying to call a method from a different directory but getting an error saying that the method is not present. I have the method present with the first letter Uppercase.

I have the following directory structure

```
[laptop@laptop src]$ tree
.
├── hello
│   ├── hello.go
├── remote_method
│   └── remoteMethod.go
```

My main is in hello.go and tries to call a function from the remote_method package

```
package main
import 
 (
        "remote_method"
 )

func main() {
     mm := remote_method.NewObject()
     mm.MethodCall()
}
```

The remoteMethod.go has the following contents

```
package remote_method

import (
.....
)

type DeclaredType struct {
        randomMap (map[string][](chan int))
}

func NewObject() DeclaredType {
        var randomMap (map[string][](chan int))
        m := DeclaredType{randomMap}
        return m
}

func MethodCall(m DeclaredType, param1 string, param2 string, param3 string, param4 string) {
     // Code to be run
}
```

I get the error

```
mm.MethodCall undefined (type remote_method.DeclaredType has no field or method MethodCall)
```

Can someone help me in finding why the method is not visible or any possible ways I could find that. 
TIA

Comment: well `MethodCall` is not a member of your `DeclaredType` struct

Comment: Take a look at the [Tour of Go](https://tour.golang.org/methods/1), method declarations are explained well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Register MethodCall() as a receiver in DeclaredType.

**remote_method.go**

```
package remote_method

import (
.....
)

type DeclaredType struct {
        randomMap (map[string][](chan int))
}

func NewObject() DeclaredType {
        var randomMap (map[string][](chan int))
        m := DeclaredType{randomMap}
        return m
}

func (d DeclaredType) MethodCall(m DeclaredType, param1 string, param2 string, param3 string, param4 string) {
     // Code to be run
}
```